# Why don't I get client.postMessage on the client?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have this code in my service worker:

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log("onBackgroundMessage email and contact_link:");
  console.log(payload.data.email,payload.data.contact_link);

  self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
    clients.forEach(client => client.postMessage({
      msg: "This is a message from the SW",
      email: payload.data.email,
      contact_link: payload.data.contact_link
    }));
})
});
```

I have this code on the client:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', payload => {
  console.log("Message from ServiceWorker");
  console.log(payload.data.msg, payload.data.email, payload.data.contact_link);
});
```

I get the data properly on the console from the service worker, however the client's console says all the data is undefined.
Why is that, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I still do not know why it does not work, but I used this code on the server:

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
channel.postMessage(payload.data);
```

And this code on the client instead:

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
channel.addEventListener('message', event => {
    console.log('Received:', event.data);
});
```

It works well.